# How to use 'default' value within template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm facing following problem:

I have *some* generic container, that is able to do *some* operations on types. The operations are, for simplicity, thread safe, when requested to. And, **requested to** means that the type in container has `typedef std::true_type needs_thread_safety;`.

```
struct thread_safe_item {
    typedef std::true_type needs_thread_safety;
    /* */ 
};

struct thread_unsafe_item {
    typedef std::false_type needs_thread_safety;
    /* */
};
template<typename TItem> container {
    /* some algorithms, that are std::enable_if selected, according to needs_thread_safety */
};
```

But, I want the `needs_thread_safety` to be opt-in, and not needed to be defined (= default false_type). I've tried following:

```
    struct thread_unsafe_item {
        /* */ 
    };

template<typename TItem>
struct thread_safety_selector
{
    template<typename T>
    struct has_defined_thread_safety
    {
        typedef char yes[1];
        typedef char no[2];

        template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::needs_thread_safety*);
        template <typename> static no& test(...);

        static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
    };

    typedef 
        typename std::conditional<
            has_defined_thread_safety<TItem>::value,
            typename TItem::needs_thread_safety,
            std::false_type
        >::type needs_thread_safety;
};
....
struct <typename TItem> container {
    /* changed all TItem::needs_thread_safety selectors to thread_safety_selector<TItem>::needs_thread_safety */
};
```

But there is apparently no lazy-evaluation going on, as the error is `error C2039: 'needs_thread_safety' : is not a member of 'thread_unsafe_item'`.

How can I achieve default value for the argument not specified?

It is for educational purposes, so I don't need different way how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually I'm using type selectors to specify a particular base class of my final class, where the bases contain the appropriate implementations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `std::conditional` for that, as that will always parse all of its arguments. You can create your own predicate:

```
template <bool, class>
struct get_thread_safety;

template <class T>
struct get_thread_safety<true, T>
{
  typedef typename T::needs_thread_safety type;
};

template <class T>
struct get_thread_safety<false, T>
{
  typedef std::false_type type;
};

// Used like this:

typedef 
    typename get_thread_safety<
        has_defined_thread_safety<TItem>::value,
        TItem
    >::type needs_thread_safety;
```

Comment: +1, but it's possible to use `std::conditional`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this can be done a bit easier using `std::enable_if` coupled with `std::conditional`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Classes to be checked against needs_thread_safety
struct A {};
struct B { typedef std::true_type needs_thread_safety; };
struct C { typedef std::false_type needs_thread_safety; };

// Checker helper
template<class T> class get_thread_safety
{
    typedef char(&zero_size_t)[0];

    template <class X> static typename std::enable_if<X::needs_thread_safety::value, char>::type check(int);
    template <class X> static typename std::enable_if<!X::needs_thread_safety::value, zero_size_t>::type check(int);
    template <class X> static zero_size_t check(...);

public:
    typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(check<T>(0)), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type type;
};

int main()
{
   // Usage. Will print 0 1 0
   std::cout << get_thread_safety<A>::type::value << std::endl;     
   std::cout << get_thread_safety<B>::type::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << get_thread_safety<C>::type::value << std::endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `std::conditional` in a lazy way, you just need to avoid to use the nested typedef inside its template parameter list. You'll also need another fallback type for the `false` case ("default value", as you called it):

```
template<typename TItem>
struct thread_safety_selector
{
    template<typename T>
    struct has_defined_thread_safety
    {
        typedef char yes[1];
        typedef char no[2];

        template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::needs_thread_safety*);
        template <typename> static no& test(...);

        static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
    };

    // this would be your "default value"
    struct not_thread_safe {
        typedef std::false_type needs_thread_safety;
    };

    typedef
        typename std::conditional<
            has_defined_thread_safety<TItem>::value,
            TItem,   // <---- note, not using the typedef here
            not_thread_safe
        >::type::needs_thread_safety  needs_thread_safety;
     //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     //  lazily, after the selection is done
};
```

Comment: Instead of `yes` and `no` (and the `sizeof`), you can use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` as return types (and then, `decltype(test<T>(0))::value` if necessary).